# One cpu core working harder than the rest

Tags: windows, cpu, task-manager, multi-core

I have seen that with my AMD A8 cpu one of the cores is working harder than the rest. See below:

[image]

The running processes:
[image]

Does any one know if this is a problem or just a natural assurance.

Comment: The majority of your running processes are likely single threaded applications that specifically target the first CPU that is detected by their code.

Comment: Yep, it would be helpful if you can let us know what process was running at that time to understand if that was the issue

Comment: @SandeepBansal See edits

Comment: You should click the `Show processes from all users` button if you want to see which process it taking up resources...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal.

Most programs and services will execute a task using the first cpu core that it can get access to.  Normally, a program will have to be specifically coded to work with multiple cores.

Windows does not distribute taskls across cores unfortunately - which is a shame.

Comment: Well it's not a shame - it's to save power. If you use all four cores for one process it'll end up using more power. Using one core for the load will leave less of a footprint and leave the other cores for other work.

Comment: technically speaking - yes.  The more work something does, then generally the less lifespan it will have.  That said, CPUs generally last so long that by the time a cpu core dies, you should have replaced it a long time ago!  Really, its nothing to be worried about!

Comment: @09stephenb - A processor is designed to be used.  Its total lifespan would not change even if every single core was running at 100% 24/7.  If your system is properly cooled then said usage I describe would not be a problem.

Comment: @sandeep.. you have a point, but it can also be argued (particularly in a desktop, server or plugged in laptop environment) that since you spent so much money on a nice quad - it would be nice to be able to happily hammer all 4 cores without having to specifically get hold of multi-thread capable software

Comment: @Fazer87 I wasn't talking about lifecycle or temperature of the processor. I was more focused on the power it'll use. It's all about efficiency. And yes it would be nice to use all the cores but if they're technically not needed and won't give any gain on the application then there's no point in using them

Comment: I will again point out. A process can only use additional cores if its program to do so. Windows does not a great deal of say in the matter. An operating system is determines which process will be sent to the processor next, the program itself, will determine how many threads it require to do a specific instruction. I have simplified that entire process since multiple people seem confused.  The lifespan of the processor itself won't change because a single "core" in the case of an Intel processor is used more then the other cores.